# share cookies between clients

Tags: cookies, server, client, shared

I would like to know if it's possible to share cookies between 2 clients (or more client, like PC) ?
In my vision, we have a cookies server to share cookies to another PC with a web client (chrome or firefox). When the client connect to a website, the browser search the cookie on the cookie's server and get it. If the cookie is expired, the client send the new cookie to the server. Other client can get it.

I think the concept technically possible, but I didn't find anything like that on the web.

[Edit]
The question is : There is already a program that allows to centralize and manage cookies (server) ? And client program with

Comment: Not sure what is your question, but you could do it with a plugin on your browser

Comment: Yes, sorry i forgot the real question. I had edited it. Which plugin is it ?

Comment: I thought you wanted to know if it is possible to build something like this. It is probably possible. But is there something which already does it ? I don't know, probably not.